# Remove jquery repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have jQuery function which toggles a ckeditor text field on click.

My .js file:

```
$(function() {
  $(".add-greeting").on("click", function(event){
    $(".panel-body").find('#add-greeting').slideToggle(400,
      function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#add-greeting').offset().top +   $('window').height()
        }, 1000);
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

My html.erb file:

```
<div class="form-group", style="padding-bottom:0px;">
  <%= link_to "Add greeting", "#", class: "add-greeting btn btn-sm btn-success" %>
</div>

<div id="add-greeting" style="float:left; display:none;">
  <%= f.input :offer_greeting, value: offer_settings(@offer, :offer_greeting), as: :ckeditor %>
</div>
```

The problem is, I have 2 ckeditor fields, so 2 buttons, which now translates into 2 identical jQuery functions, the only difference being the classes and ids I am passing in.

```
$(function() {
  $(".add-observations").on("click", function(event){
    $(".panel-body").find('#add-observations').slideToggle(400,
      function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#add-observations').offset().top + $('window').height()
        }, 1000);
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

Rendered html:

```
<div class="form-group", style="padding-bottom:0px;">
  <a class="add-greeting btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#">Add greeting</a>
</div>
<div id="add-greeting" style="float: left; display: none;">
  <div class="control-group ckeditor optional offer_offer_greeting"><label class="ckeditor optional" for="offer_offer_greeting">Greeting</label>...
```

How can I avoid repetition?

Comment: can you show the rendered html please

Comment: Why don't you use common classes for all elements and use any transversal method to target specific element or index?

Comment: @BogdanPopa, have added an answer that may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this then you only need to give each link the class of `.animate-scroll`

Change link to have href to id you want to scroll to and shared class:

```
<a class="animate-scroll btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#add-greeting">Add greeting</a>
```

Update jQuery to:

```
var scrollable = $('html, body');
$(".animate-scroll").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var elem = $($(this).attr('href'));

    elem.slideToggle(400,
    function () {
        scrollable.animate({
            scrollTop: elem.offset().top + $(window).height() // no need for quotes around window
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ya seems really better way and this would handle no js user btw, minus animations of course

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, I have 2 ckeditor fields, so 2 buttons, which now translates into 2 identical jQuery functions, the only difference being the classes and ids I am passing in.

In that case, a plugin might help. Try building your repetitive code as a jQuery plugin and reuse it with different ids or classes.

Few references to get you started

- [How to create a basic plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)
- [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#jquerypluginpatterns)